# Put strings from text to different variables in bash

Tags: bash

There is a textfile in which the 1st line is `link`, the 2nd is `username`, and the 3rd is `gallery`:

```
http://sitename.com/galleries/1
1-username
gallery 1
http://sitename.com/galleries/2
2-username
gallery 2
http://sitename.com/galleries/3
1-username
gallery 3
http://sitename.com/galleries/4
2-username
gallery 4
http://sitename.com/galleries/5
3-username
gallery 5
```

For each `link` need to `curl` it, `grep` some image's links and download them using `wget` to folder named like `gallery` inside the folder named like `username`.
For example, need to have such folder's structure:

```
\1-username\gallery 1
\2-username\gallery 2
\1-username\gallery 3
\2-username\gallery 4
\3-username\gallery 5
```

frame of code (used 2 backquotes for `sed` output variable):

``` | curl $link | egrep 'PATTERN' | for image in ``sed -e "s/PATTERN/\\1/"`` do wget $image -P "\\$username\\$gallery";done ```

How to set different variables for strings in cylce while reading such textfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mod operator and a counter to read the file like so in order to get the right variables e.g.

```
C=0
while read line; do
    if (( (C % 3) == 0 )); then 
        link=$line
    elif (( (C % 3) == 1 )); then
        username=$line
    else
        gallery=$line
        #Do what you want with the varible here
        echo "$link - $username - $gallery"
    fi
    C=$((C+1)) #Counter
done < file.txt
```

#### Explanation:

- Set counter to zero
- Loop through each line in the file
  & If the counter mod 3 is 0, set link variable to the current line
- if the counter mod 3 is 1, set username variable to the current line
- Other wise(ie. if the counter mod 3 is 2), set the gallery variable to the current line and execute your code with the three variables.
- Increment the counter for the next iteration.

I'm just echoing the variables, the output of which is below but you can run your code there instead.

```
http://sitename.com/galleries/1 - 1-username - gallery 1
http://sitename.com/galleries/2 - 2-username - gallery 2
http://sitename.com/galleries/3 - 1-username - gallery 3
http://sitename.com/galleries/4 - 2-username - gallery 4
http://sitename.com/galleries/5 - 3-username - gallery 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '/http/{p=NR;next} NR==p+1{u=$0;next} NR==p+2{print "\\" u "\\" $0; p=""}' file
\1-username\gallery 1
\2-username\gallery 2
\1-username\gallery 3
\2-username\gallery 4
\3-username\gallery 5
```

Comment: thanx, please more detailed explanations how to handle with vars from this expression

Comment: Pls clarify what you mean by `how to handle with vars from this expression`?